# Wordpress Memory Exceeds after User login

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom login for wordpress to let user login automatically into wordpress via a custom form on another page that is not on wordpress but on the same hosting. The form saves the name in a cookie and then redirects user to wordpress homepage where the plugin logins user using the following code  :

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {

   $user_login = $_COOKIE['user_name_from_the_form'];

   //get user's ID
    $user = get_userdatabylogin($user_login);
    $user_id = $user->ID;
             
    //login
    wp_set_current_user($user_id, $user_login);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
    do_action('wp_login', $user_login);}
```

The problem is, this code sucessfully logins the user but if i visit homepage of the website , then it gives runtime error. All other pages work fine but on homepage, it gives runtime Application error (A yellow page open and shows "Server Error in '/' Application" .

If i disable the plugin and login to wordpress via wordpress login form, then it doesn't give any error.

**I tried increasing the memory limit from php.ini to 128MB but this fixed the problem temporarily.** After some time, if i refresh the homepage several times, this error again occurs.

Please guide me if there is any error in the code or something else. Thank you.

If i logout user via following code

```
wp_destroy_current_session();
   wp_clear_auth_cookie();
   wp_logout();
```

and refresh the home page, it works fine.

I have set the cookie time 3600 (i.e 1 hour).

Here is the complete function, that i am using :

```
function manage_user(){

if (isset($_COOKIE['user_name_from_the_form'])){} else {return 0;}

   if ($_COOKIE['user_name_from_the_form'] != '0') {

          if (!is_user_logged_in()) {

   $user_login = $_COOKIE['user_name_from_the_form'];

   //get user's ID
    $user = get_userdatabylogin($user_login);
    $user_id = $user->ID;
             
    //login
    wp_set_current_user($user_id, $user_login);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
    do_action('wp_login', $user_login);}

} else {

   wp_destroy_current_session();
   wp_clear_auth_cookie();
   wp_logout();

}}  
add_action('init', 'manage_user');
```

Comment: Give some more memory. Every extra plugin eats more.

Comment: How to increase memory for my custom plugin ? Its just a login/logout function. why its eating so much memory ?

Comment: why the error just occurs on homepage and not on any other page ?

Comment: You can not increase for a plugin, only either for a particular script or in general. Use the php.ini as before and double it and then watch if it is enough.

Comment: Hello @JohnSmith please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please add in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');
define('WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I tried your solution but still it giving the same error. This is the snapshot of the error , i get: 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S6z-QeNGY4Vq41nlYhuA033NbVYJkX2B/view?usp=sharing


Please note that only on homepage this error occurs. When i visit any other webpage of the website, it works absolutely fine.